# Cake php js helper, using jquery append

Tags: ajax, cakephp, append

```
 <?php 
 echo $this->Js->submit('Submit',array(
  'before' => $this->Js->get('#beforesend')->effect('fadeIn', array('buffer' => false)),
  'complete' => $this->Js->get('#beforesend')->effect('fadeOut', array('buffer' => false)),
   'update' => '#contentc'

));?>
```

i was able to create an ajax call with the above code.
but what i want is to create multiple ajax request and append the output to previous ajax output.

my code overwrites the div simply because i have given an "update"
is there any way by which i can use jquery append.

Answer (score 0):

You might be better off setting update to a hidden div, and then copy or move the contents of that hidden div to append to #contentc as a part of the complete action.

Answer (score 0):

Generating javascript by passing php array is good in the case of simple function, but this is kind of difficult when you try for complex one, 
So what i did was simply create a page with the javascript functions and add it in the $content_for_script variable.